# ERROR 2002 on Fedora 39: MySQL Server Can’t Connect Through Socket ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets

I’m having a problem after installing MySQL. I tried to start MySQL, set it up, but I receive the following error: "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’ (2)"

I’ve tried some solutions that I saw here on Stack and other places, but none of them worked. If anyone can help me, I’m using Fedora 39.

I've already checked my my.cnf file and the socket is configured correctly, but I noticed that in the path to socket(/var/lib/mysql), the socket(mysql.sock) file was not created, I've tried to reinstall and some other processes, but none solved

Answer (score -5):

It seems like there might be a few issues causing the problem. Here are some steps you can follow to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

1. **Check if MySQL is Running:**
   Ensure that MySQL is running. You can use the following command to check its status:

   sudo systemctl status mysqld

   If MySQL is not running, start it using:

   sudo systemctl start mysqld
2. **Check for Error Logs:**
   Examine the MySQL error log to get more information about the issue:

   sudo journalctl -xe | grep mysql

   Look for any error messages that might provide clues about what's going wrong.
3. **Verify MySQL Socket Path:**
   Confirm that the `my.cnf` file has the correct socket path. Open the file:

   sudo nano /etc/my.cnf

   Make sure the `socket` entry is pointing to the correct location. It should be something like:

   socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

   Save the file and restart MySQL:

   sudo systemctl restart mysqld
4. **Check MySQL Data Directory:**
   Confirm that the MySQL data directory exists and has the correct permissions. The default data directory is usually `/var/lib/mysql`. Ensure that the MySQL user has the necessary permissions:

   sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
5. **Reinstall MySQL:**
   If the issue persists, you might consider reinstalling MySQL. Before doing this, make sure to backup your databases if needed.

   sudo dnf remove mysql-server
   sudo dnf install mysql-server

   After reinstalling, start MySQL and check if the issue is resolved.
6. **Manual Socket Creation:**
   If the socket file is still not created, you can try manually creating it:

   sudo touch /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
   sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

   After that, restart MySQL and see if the problem persists.
7. **Check SELinux:**
   If you are using SELinux, it might be restricting MySQL's access. Check SELinux status:

   sestatus

   If SELinux is in enforcing mode, try temporarily disabling it and see if the issue persists:

   sudo setenforce 0

   If this solves the problem, you may need to configure SELinux policies for MySQL.

After trying these steps, hopefully, you'll be able to resolve the issue. If the problem persists, reviewing the error logs and any additional error messages would be crucial for further troubleshooting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy